# Creating a perceptual map using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm looking to create a **perceptual map** using highcharts; however, I'm running into some difficulties.

I'm currently using the scatter plot chart as a starting point and manually adjusting the x-axis and y-axis to create a 4-piece grid.

Has anyone used highcharts for this type of data development?  If so, how did you structure the chart?  Here's an example of a perceptual map/what I'm trying to create (for reference): **[Perceptual Map](http://lukethomas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Apple-Perceptual-Map.jpg)**

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle with what you tried so far and what you want to achieve? Might turn to be really easier to get an aswer.

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values) plugin to divide chart into for sections. Missing elements / labels can be added by [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text)